# Regex case-insensitive searches not matching the exact word

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the following regex to search for 3 different string formats, concurrently. Additionally, I'm using `re.IGNORECASE` to match upper and lower case strings. However, when I perform a search (e.g. 'locality'), I'm able to get string matches for 'localit', 'locali', 'local' and so on and so forth.  I want to match the exact word (eg. 'locality').

Also, if there is white space between string characters (eg., `'l ocal i ty'`), I want to ignore it. I have not found a `re` method that allows me to do that. I tried using `re.ASCII`, but I get an error: "...ascii is invalid!" Any assistance is appreciated.

```
elif searchType =='2':
  print "  Directory to be searched: c:\Python27 "
  directory = os.path.join("c:\\","Python27")
  userstring = raw_input("Enter a string name to search: ")
  userStrHEX = userstring.encode('hex')
  userStrASCII = ' '.join(str(ord(char)) for char in userstring)
  regex = re.compile(r"(%s|%s|%s)" % ( re.escape( userstring ), re.escape( userStrHEX ), re.escape( userStrASCII ))re.IGNORECASE)
  for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
     for file in files:
         if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
            f=open(os.path.join(root, file))
            for line in f.readlines():
               #if userstring in line:
               if regex.search(line):       
                  print "file: " + os.path.join(root,file)           
                  break
            else:
               #print "String NOT Found!"
               break
            f.close()
```

Comment: Please show us some specific examples of the three user strings and the string you're searching in. Also, please say what you're getting and what you'd like to get.

Comment: If you want to ignore white space between characters, then you probably need to insert a `\s*` in between each character in the original strings you are searching for.

Comment: Please fix formatting of your source code - four spaces in front of each line and indent appropriately.

Comment: @tchrist: whitespace-sensitive and highly allergic to sideways mustaches {  ... :P

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma before `re.IGNORECASE` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such flag in re, so either:

- construct a regex with explicit whitespace-matching after every char:

  `r'\s*'.join(c for c in userStrASCII)`

  This works: `myre.findall(line)` finds 'l Oc ALi ty'
- or (if you only need to detect matches to the pattern, but not do anything further with the actual match text) use `string.translate(,deleteChars)` to strip whitespace from the line before matching. e.g. do `line.translate(None, ' \t\n\r').lower()` before you try to match. (Keep a copy of the unsquelched line.)